# Deploy at Gitlab CI with docker-compose fails

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I deployed my app from the local machine before by:

```
> docker context create remote --docker "host=ssh://user@myhost" 
> docker --context remote ps 
> docker-compose --context remote build 
> docker-compose --context remote up -d
```

This is successful, all Dockerfiles are right.
Now I want to do the same but at GitLab CI. This is my gitlab-ci.yml file for building:

```
image: docker:19.03.12
services:
  - docker:dind  
  
stages:
  - build

install_dependencies:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'

    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no " > ~/.ssh/config
  script:
    - echo "Building deploy package"
    - echo "$NPMRC" > ~/.npmrc
    - apk add --no-cache docker-compose
    - docker context create remote --docker "host=ssh://user@myhost"
    - docker --context remote ps
    - docker context use remote
    - docker-compose --context remote build
    - echo "Build successful"
```

Everything goes right before `docker-compose --context remote build`, when --context arg is not recognized, I can't understand why.

```
$ docker context use remote
 Current context is now "remote"
 Warning: DOCKER_HOST environment variable overrides the active context. To use "remote", either set the global --context flag, or unset DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
 remote
 $ docker-compose --context remote build
 Define and run multi-container applications with Docker.
 Usage:
   docker-compose [-f <arg>...] [options] [COMMAND] [ARGS...]
   docker-compose -h|--help
 Options:
   -f, --file FILE             Specify an alternate compose file
                               (default: docker-compose.yml)
   -p, --project-name NAME     Specify an alternate project name
                               (default: directory name)
   --verbose                   Show more output
   --log-level LEVEL           Set log level (DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL)
   --no-ansi                   Do not print ANSI control characters
   -v, --version               Print version and exit
   -H, --host HOST             Daemon socket to connect to
   --tls                       Use TLS; implied by --tlsverify
   --tlscacert CA_PATH         Trust certs signed only by this CA
   --tlscert CLIENT_CERT_PATH  Path to TLS certificate file
   --tlskey TLS_KEY_PATH       Path to TLS key file
   --tlsverify                 Use TLS and verify the remote
   --skip-hostname-check       Don't check the daemon's hostname against the
                               name specified in the client certificate
   --project-directory PATH    Specify an alternate working directory
                               (default: the path of the Compose file)
   --compatibility             If set, Compose will attempt to convert keys
                               in v3 files to their non-Swarm equivalent
   --env-file PATH             Specify an alternate environment file
 Commands:
   build              Build or rebuild services
   config             Validate and view the Compose file
   create             Create services
   down               Stop and remove containers, networks, images, and volumes
   events             Receive real time events from containers
   exec               Execute a command in a running container
   help               Get help on a command
   images             List images
   kill               Kill containers
   logs               View output from containers
   pause              Pause services
   port               Print the public port for a port binding
   ps                 List containers
   pull               Pull service images
   push               Push service images
   restart            Restart services
   rm                 Remove stopped containers
   run                Run a one-off command
   scale              Set number of containers for a service
   start              Start services
   stop               Stop services
   top                Display the running processes
   unpause            Unpause services
   up                 Create and start containers
   version            Show the Docker-Compose version information
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: What version do you use for docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @Vladimir version "3.7"

Comment: @Vladimir also I'm confused about  docker-compose --version:  docker-compose version 1.25.4, build unknown

Comment: Can you try using the :latest image for docker?

Comment: If this doesn't work, try increasing the docker-compose version. I think they added support for contexts in the 1.26.0 version.

Comment: @Vladimir thank you! I catched a lot of errors during docker-compose update but finally fixed them . But I have one more question, how to save all configurations of the image and don't install packages every time?

Comment: @Vladimir You're almost right - `docker-compose` supports contexts starting with version 1.26.0-rc2: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.26.0-rc2

Comment: For not installing always those packages, you could use a gitlab agent on your server, login on your server with a gitlab token and have there all the packages you need.

Comment: @Vladimir Gitlab agent you mean is gitlab runner? Can you give an example of such procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, docker-compose version should be at least `1.26.0`.